# How to make draggable pop over in bootstrap using jquery or css?

Tags: jquery, html, draggable, popover, movable

I want to draggable or movable popover because when there are two popover open in one page then two popover are overlapped by each other. For this thing you can check below screenshot.
[image]

So i want to move popover using the mouse cursor pointer where i want to place. So i can see both popover at same time.

My already code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Popover Example</h3>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">Toggle popover1</a>
  <br/>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">Toggle popover2</a>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I think i can use draggable function but it is not working i don't know how exactly way to apply on jQuery so it can be work.

According my need you can check this movable modal, I need this same movable action on my popover. For this please check below screenshot of gif and link for more understanding.
Link: https://codepen.io/adamcjoiner/pen/PNbbbv
[image]

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use data-placement="..." in your "a" tag to handle where popovers should open.
For example in your code it can be like :

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Popover Example</h3>
  <p>Popovers are not CSS-only plugins, and must therefore be initialized with jQuery: select the specified element and call the popover() method.</p>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover" data-placement="top">First popover</a>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover" data-placement="bottom">Second popover</a>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

the values inside data-placement can be :top-bottom-right and left

UPDATE:
I think it will work for you :

```js
$(".draggable").popover({
    html:true,
    content: "<p>Drag me</p>"

}).popover('show');

$('.popover').draggable();
```

```css
    .popover{position: relative !important}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"
 integrity="sha256-0vBSIAi/8FxkNOSKyPEfdGQzFDak1dlqFKBYqBp1yC4="
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
 
<div class="row">
  <div class ="col-auto">
  <h2>
   sendhelp
  </h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="Normal">
    <a class="btn btn-primary draggable">Popover</a>
</div>
```

UPDATE 2:
I made a fiddle and you can use it :
https://jsfiddle.net/uhwrev06/

Now it moves exactly with the mouse without no space between them !

UPDATE 3:
I fixed the problem you just mentioned!
https://jsfiddle.net/pe2zf1x8/

Comment: You can check this https://codepen.io/adamcjoiner/pen/PNbbbv link and you can move the modal i need this movable action on my popover using the mouse.

Comment: Check  my edited answer for exact understanding of my need.

Comment: Check this fiddle ,But remember to remove the css:https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/153665/

Comment: Ohh really good as per my need. But you can tell me how can make less distance between mouse cursor and popover box? So it can make it perfect.

Comment: I fixed it and i updated my answer ! just add this : .popover{position: relative !important} to css part

Comment: Can you give me code in jsfiddle? Because i have checked at my end but it will show popup by default before on click of pop link. So if you give me fiddle link show we can check properly

Comment: I made a fiddle for you! i inserted the link in the answer ... please mark it as answer if it works for you  ! Good Luck

Comment: Now you have remove some space between cursor and popup. But can you reduce the distance between the button and popup when it was show.
http://prntscr.com/mgc3eq

Comment: Check The answer again. I update fiddle and fix the bug! please mark it as answer if it works for you ! Good Luck

Comment: Ohh Really thank you. You are real hero. Thanks for help until my problem has been completed as solved. Thanks again.

Comment: You are Welcome ... I am glad that i helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:
Try taking control over popover and overriding the CSS.

```
 $('#elm').popover({
        placement: 'bottom',
        html: true,
        content: function() {
            return $('#container').html();
        },


        template: '<div class="popover my-popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-content"></div></div>'
    });
```

**CSS sample:**

```
.popover.my-popover {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: -20px;

    /* Or: margin: -20px 0 0 15px; */
}
```

**Subscribing to the shown.bs.popover Event:**

```
$('#my-popover').on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
    // parseInt removes "px"
    var currentTop = parseInt($(this).css('top'));
    var currentLeft = parseInt($(this).css('left'));

    $(this).css({
        top: (currentTop + 200) + 'px',
        left: (currentLeft + 150) + 'px'
    });
});
```

Comment: According your answer I have got one idea to just add placement at bottom  thanks for this. But i want draggable popover using the mouse cursor then we want place to other where we want.

Comment: You can check this https://codepen.io/adamcjoiner/pen/PNbbbv link and you can move the modal i need this movable action on my popover.